# How to delete property in JS and map new object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

wanted to remove properties that has matching errorCode and transform new object once all filtering is done, I am not getting below expected response any idea what is the issue with below code ?

if settlementCode matches with drugPriceErrors findErrCode should return true.

main.js

```
const data = [{
            "isBrand": true,
            "drugName": "Lipitor",
            "mailPrice": {
                "totalQuantity": 90,
                "rejectMessage": [{
                    "settlementCode": "99",
                    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
                }]
            },
            "retailPrice": {
                "totalQuantity": 30,
                "rejectMessage": [{
                    "settlementCode": "85",
                    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
                }]
            },
            "specialtyPrice": {}
        },
        {
            "isBrand": false,
            "drugName": "Atorvastatin Calcium",
            "drugStrength": "80mg",
            "drugForm": "Tablet",
            "mailPrice": {
                "totalQuantity": 90,
                "rejectMessage": [{
                    "settlementCode": "99",
                    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
                }]
            },
            "retailPrice": {
                "totalQuantity": 30,
                "rejectMessage": [{
                    "settlementCode": "99",
                    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
                }]
            },
            "specialtyPrice": {}
        }
    ];

const drugPricesErrors = [99,45,89];

function filterDrugs (data) { 
  const response = [];
const _drugPrice = data.map(item => {
        const retailHasCode = findErrCode(item.retailPrice.rejectMessage);
        const mailHasCode = findErrCode (item.mailPrice.rejectMessage);

        if(retailHasCode) {
            delete item.retailPrice;
        }

        if(mailHasCode) {
            delete item.mailPrice;
        }

  return item;

    });

    _.forEach(_drugPrice, function(drug) {
        if(drug.retailPrice !== undefined || drug.mailPrice !== undefined){
            response.push(drug);
        }
    });

  return response;
}

function findErrCode(data) {
    const filterMessage = data.filter( message => drugPriceErrors.includes(item.settlementCode));
    return filterMessage;
}
```

expected output

```
[{
            "isBrand": true,
            "drugName": "Lipitor",
            "retailPrice": {
                "totalQuantity": 30,
                "rejectMessage": [{
                    "settlementCode": "85",
                    "settlementDesc": "Sorry, the system is temporarily:Lo sentimos,Intente(Código de error 85)"
                }]
            },
            "specialtyPrice": {}
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: current ouput is returning all the objects that contians error codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `findErrCode` to something like this:

```
let findErrCode = data => 
  data.some(i => drugPriceErrors.includes(Number(i.settlementCode)))
```

Key is to use `Number` to convert your `settlementCode` so the `Array.some` works. Also use `Array.some` since you only care if the result is true or false (Boolean). `Array.filter` would actually return records etc.

You can see it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fhk8gyu0/)